# will Cassandra-spark-connector accepts timestamp datatype from a cassandra table?

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Am using spark-cassandra-connector to perform some analysis via spark in cassandra tables. Everything was working fine until i changed one of my text filed into a timestamp field. Once i done it its giving me an error

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Invalid 32-bits integer value, expecting 4 bytes but got 0
```

my code is follows,

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> rddd = functions.cassandraTable("test",
            "activity_log");
System.out.println("rddd--- "+rddd.toArray());
```

Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: you probably have a null value. This page gives some guidance in the use of null values in Scala: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#working-with-nullable-data